# Open HTML page in a new window in Wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have a button (or link), and if I click on it, I want to open a HTML file. But I don't have the file, I have only the byte array of the HTML file. How could I open it in a new window, if I click on my opener button, to display the HTML file? Thank you!

Comment: http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/How-to-write-HTML-directly-td1844138.html

Answer (score 1):

You should make servlet which shows content of you html page. Example:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException  {

    resp.setContentType("text/html");

    // implement your page generations business logic in getHtmlPage
    InputStream htmlPage = getHtmlPage();
    OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

    // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

I don't know how you exactly can determinate, which page you must show, so I encapsulate it into getHtmlPage method. Simplest way is make cache with pages and transfer into servlet page's key.

Comment: You don't need a servlet for this with wicket. See the link from @Joachim Rohde above

Comment: Do you talk about setEscapeMode? I don't think that is good solution for question.